# Which $Y \subseteq \{a,b,c,d\}$ satisfy $Y - B = X - B$, where $B = \{b,d\}$ and $X = \{a,b\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am having a problem with my math assignment, and i'm honestly not even sure of where to begin with this one.

The question is:

> Let $A=\{a,b,c,d\}$, $B = \{b,d\}$ and $X = \{a,b\}$. Determine all $Y\in\mathcal{P}(A)$ such that $Y - B = X - B$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$X-B=\{a\}$ so you have to find sets $Y \in  \mathcal{P}(A)$ s.t. $Y-B=\{a\}$. Since $B$={b,d}, the answer is:
$\{a\},\{a,b\}$,and $\{a,b,d\}$

EDITED:

Since $\mathcal{P}(A)=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{d\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{a,d\},\{b,c\},\{b,d\},\{c,d\},\{a,b,c\},\{a,b,d\},\{a,c,d\},\{b,c,d\},\{a,b,c,d\}\}$,

you only have to try to substract $\{b,d\}$ from this sets.

Comment: Would you be able to explain of how you got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

We can begin by identifying that $X-B=\{a,b\}-\{b,d\}=\{a\}$.

So the question asks: *For which $Y \subseteq \{a,b,c,d\}$ do we have $Y-\overbrace{\{b,d\}}^B=\{a\}$?*

Suppose $x \in \{a,b,c,d\}$.  Then:

- If some $x \not\in Y$, then $x \not\in Y-\{b,d\}$.  This implies that $a$ must be in $Y$.
- If some $x \in Y$ while $x \not\in \{b,d\}$, then $x \in Y-\{b,d\}$.  This implies that $c$ must not be in $Y$.
- If $x \in \{b,d\}$, then $x \not\in Y-\{b,d\}$.  So, $b$ and/or $d$ may or may not be in $Y$; it has no effect on whether $b$ or $d$ is in $Y-\{b,d\}$.

This gives the four possibilities for $Y$: $$\{a\},\{a,b\},\{a,d\},\{a,b,d\}.$$

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. That is a great explanation.